# How can I reduce a JavaPairRDD

Tags: apache-spark

I have a JavaPairRDD representing the counts for each word in a file. I would like to find the maximum of this RDD just as an exercise (i realize there is a function).

So i wrote the following code

```
Tuple2<String,Integer> max = counts.reduce(new Function2<Tuple2<String,Integer>,Tuple2<String,Integer>,Tuple2<String,Integer>>(){
        public Tuple2<String,Integer> call(Tuple2<String,Integer> a,Tuple2<String,Integer> b) {
            if(a._2>b._2) {
                return a;
            }
            return b;
        }
    });
```

Which gives me a NoSuchMethodException, So i was wondering what would be the correct way to reduce such an RDD.

EDIT: Here's the whole error

```
./spark-submit --class sparkApp --master spark://url simpleApp.jar
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sparkApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full exception stacktrace? Thanks!

Comment: It seems more like a java problem than a spark problem. Were you able to execute a simple code in `sparkApp` ?

Comment: Yeah, the actual word count works fine. I've read that this exception occurs if the compiled library differs from the one used at runtime which is why i specified the exact version of spark that im using. can't think of anything else that might be causing this and googling has brought up nothing othere than this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1834

Comment: Can you verify that the sparkApp class is present in your simpleApp jar?

Comment: Yes, I can run the rest of the code in the class just fine.

Comment: Please post your maven/packaging procedure too :)